# ABPersonViewController Not Saving Changes

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

In the app I am writing, I allow users to associate contacts with events. They can add new or existing contacts using the Address Book UI Framework.

Once the contacts are associated, they are displayed, and the user can click them to bring up an `ABPersonViewController`. Editing appears to work, but when the person view is closed, the changes are not saved.

Here is the relevant code:

```
ABPersonViewController *personController = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
personController.personViewDelegate = self;
personController.allowsEditing = YES;
personController.displayedPerson

[self.navigationController pushViewController:personController animated:YES];

[personController release];
```

After editing a contact and closing the person view, if I click on the contact again, none of the altered information is present.

I tried creating an `ABAddressBookRef` property, and assigning it to the controller using

```
personController.addressBook = ab;
```

And then saving the address book afterwards, but that did not work either.

**EDIT:**

I already implement the `<ABPersonViewControllerDelegate>`. It only has one method, and if I recall correctly, failure to implement that would prevent the ABPersonViewController from working at all.

Here is my full implementation:

```
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    return YES;
}
```

As far as I am aware, this just means that the controller will behave normally.

**EDIT 2:**

OK, so I just realized that the controller is not displaying any information about the selected person except their name. I assume this means that my ABRecordRefs are incorrect in some way. I will investigate.

I store contacts as an array of NSNumbers containing the record IDs. Here is my code (where contactIDs is the array of record IDs, and ab is an `ABAddressBookRef`):

```
NSMutableArray *contactArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSNumber *contactNumber in contactIDs) {
    NSInteger contactID = [contactNumber intValue];
    [contactArray addObject:ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ab, contactID)];
}
```

This seems like it is working, because the correct name is loaded when I select a contact. However, no other information is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. The problem was that I was using two different ABAddressBookRefs.

I created an array of ABRecordRefs (as seen in my edited question) using one ABAddressBookRef, but when I read an ABRecordRef from the array, the ABAddressBookRef I had been using had already been released.

I made an instance of ABAddressBookRef persist throughout the full life cycle of my class instance, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all addressbook delegate method to solve this issue.
[Go to this Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the AddressBook? Did you use `ABAddressBookCreate()`?

Moreover, you should make sure that you implement the `ABPersonViewControllerDelegate` correctly.

Please check out this example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html

I believe that it consists all you need!

**Update** you should try out **ABAddressBookSave** method!

Cheers,

Thang

Comment: I already implement the delegate, and yes, I create the address book using `ABAddressBookCreate()`. I tested the sample code, and it works properly, but I cannot find the difference between it and mine.

Comment: I have done one project related to AddressBooks years ago. I don't remember exactly what I have done to fix everything. But one thing I remember is that playing with the ABAddressBookRef is very important. And using other Controller is not simply creating like usual. If you could post also the part where you get the selected person, I can take a look and might give some helps

Comment: please try this out

personController.addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

Because personController.addressBook = ab; is not correct. I have just remember :)

Comment: I just realized that the selected person is likely the issue. There isn't really a lot to screw up in the actual implementation of `ABPersonViewController`.

Comment: ab is a reference to an existing ABAddressBookRef created with ABAddressBookCreate().

Comment: forgot, you should try ABAddressBookSave method then!

Comment: As stated in my original question, I already tried that. However, from what I gather from Apple's sample code, it should not be necessary.